# Haml syntax error> Illegal elements classes and ids must have values

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, haml

My view has this:

```
%tr
   %th =link_to 'Name', :sort =>'name', :id => 'name_header'
```

My Controller method for the view has this:

```
@students = Student.order(params[:sort]).all
```

I am trying to sort by clicking on the column header.
Similarly, I tried `params[:id]` instead of `params[:sort]` but it failed too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that the Student has the column name. This will find all the students like `find_all` does ordered by the value that has key `sort` in params. We expect to be `"name"`.

```
@students = Student.find(:all, :order => 'name') if params[:sort]=='name'
```

And for your .haml, assign the `id` for the anchor tag;

```
%tr
  %th= link_to "Name", params.merge(:sort => 'name'), :id => 'name_header'
```

Or, assign the `id` to the table header.

```
%tr
  %th{:id => 'name_header'}= link_to "Name", params.merge(:sort => 'name')
```

With [**.merge()**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) you keep the old parameters and, if the link is clicked, you add the GET parameter `sort`. As I didn't realize if the `id` is for the table header of the link I put the two solutions! As an [**EXAMPLE**](https://github.com/saasbook/hw3_rottenpotatoes/) you can clone this app and see in `/movies`.

Comment: In the movie EXAMPLE, what is movies_path(:sort=>...)? Is this a function and sort is the parameter? Where is the function defined?

Comment: Take a look at 2.2 and 2.3 section in [Rails Routing from Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)

Comment: Thank you Waldyr.ar for the link.

Answer (score 2):

I can't reproduce that error, but you're passing HTML options in the place of URL options to [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to). This might fix it:

```
%th= link_to 'Name', '#', :sort =>'name', :id => 'name_header'
```

Also note that it should be

```
  %th= link_to
```

and not

```
  %th =link_to
```